# Android - MediaStore.Video.query() is returning null

Tags: android, video, media, android-mediaplayer, mediastore

I'm trying to retrieve the metadata from a video file (title, language, artist) using the method MediaStore.Video.query(). However, the method is always returning null. The code is bellow:

```
String[] columns = {
    MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns._ID,
    MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.TITLE,
    MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.ARTIST
};

Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Video.query(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), videoUri,columns);

if (cursor != null) {
  cursor.moveToNext();
}

String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.TITLE));
```

Any suggestion about how to return video metadata using android?

==Update

As I searched in many places, I tried one solution using CursorLoader. However, the method loadInBackground() from CursorLoader is also returning null. The code is showed bellow:

```
String[] columns = {
                MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.TITLE
        };

        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("content://mnt/sdcard/Movies/landscapes.mp4");

        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getBaseContext(), videoUri, columns, null, null, null);

        Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.TITLE));
```

Comment: what is `videoUri`? `MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Uri.parse("content://mnt/sdcard/Movies/landscapes.mp4")` is not an Uri for `MediaStore`. It would try to find a `ContentProvider` for authority `mnt` which does not exist.

`MediaStore` can handle only `content://media/...` Uris which you should get exclusively via `MediaStore`, not by using `Uri.parse()`.

In your case use the following for example

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
String[] columns = {
        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns._ID,
        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.TITLE,
        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.ARTIST
    };

String selection = MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA + "=?";
String selectionArgs[] = { "/mnt/sdcard/Movies/landscapes.mp4" };

Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

The `MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA` field holds the path to the videos and you search for a certain video this way. At least for now, future versions of Android may change that.

---

Your second example is using `CursorLoader` the wrong way. If you call `loader.loadInBackground()` yourself, you load the data in foreground. See e.g. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/

The next thing you do is

```
    Cursor cursor = getCursor();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String title = cursor.getString(/* some index */);
```

This will lead to a `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException` if your `cursor` has 0 rows and `cursor.moveToFirst()` failed because there is no first row. The cursor stays before the first row (at -1) and that index does not exist. That would mean in your case that the file was not found in the database.

To prevent that use the return value of `moveToFirst` - it will only be `true` if there is a first row.

```
    Cursor cursor = getCursor(); // from somewhere
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String title = cursor.getString(/* some index */);
    }
```

A more complete example including checks for `null` and closing the `cursor` in all cases

```
    Cursor cursor = getCursor(); // from somewhere
    String title = "not found";
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            title = cursor.getString(/* some index */);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
```

I guess the file you try to find is either not indexed in the database (rebooting forces the indexer to run again) or the path is wrong.

Or the path you use is actually a symlink in which case MediaStore might use a different path.

Use this to get rid of symlinks

```
    String path  = "/mnt/sdcard/Movies/landscapes.mp4";
    try {
        path = new File(path).getCanonicalPath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

---

> Yes, I tested now and it is throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException. When I'm using cursor.getColumnCount() it returns 1

`cursor.getColumnCount()` is the column count, not the row count. It should always be the same as the number of columns you requested in `columns`. You need to check `cursor.getCount()` if you want to check the row count.

---

Try dumping all the videos known to MediaStore into logcat in case it does not show as expected.

```
public static void dumpVideos(Context context) {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA };
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int vidsCount = 0;
    if (c != null) {
        vidsCount = c.getCount();
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("VIDEO", c.getString(0));
        }
        c.close();
    }
    Log.d("VIDEO", "Total count of videos: " + vidsCount);
}
```

Comment: The cursor is returning different from null. However, when I'm calling  "cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.TITLE))" it throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: @DaniloSantos if that line is throwing NPE then `cursor` is `null`. Are you sure that it is not some `IndexOutOfBoundsException` ?

Comment: Yes, I tested now and it is throwing `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. When I'm using `cursor.getColumnCount()` it returns **1**.

Comment: @DaniloSantos I guess the file was not found in MediaStore. See additions to answer.

Comment: I tested using this code:

`File new file = file("path to file");

if(file.isFile){
  log.i("ok", "test is ok");
}`

And the test shown true.

Comment: @DaniloSantos Not every existing file is in MediaStore, either because the mediascanner did not pick it up (reboot helps) or it is in a place that is not indexed at all (nothing helps). Also files can have different paths that all lead to the same file (symlinks) and if your version of that path is different from the one in MediaStore you won't find it. I've added a piece of code that simply prints all videos. Try that and check if you can find the one you seek.

Answer (score 1):

I updated your code, it works, just check it

```
public static void dumpVideos(Context context) {
Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA };
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
int vidsCount = 0;
if (c != null) {
    c.moveToFirst();
    vidsCount = c.getCount();
    do {
        Log.d("VIDEO", c.getString(0));
    }while (c.moveToNext());
    c.close();
}
Log.d("VIDEO", "Total count of videos: " + vidsCount);
}
```