# How to get the duration of video from MediaStore?

Tags: android

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613443/android-mediastore-video-query-is-returning-null) answer to get the duration,but it's not working for me.Can anybody tell me what's the problem?

Any help is appreciated.

```
 Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            String[] columns = {MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION};
            String selection = MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA + "=?";
            String selectionArgs[] = {"/data/data/com.test.test/files/video1.mp4"};
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    String duration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION));
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
```

Comment: Either the video isn't in the database, or for some reason the DATA column doesn't exactly match your path. To figure out what is going on, I suggest you try just getting all the entries in the `MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` by removing your selection and selectionArgs. You could change your columns to include the DATA column and possibly ID, and use DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor to write the contents to logcat.

Comment: @cwbowron thx for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MediaStore is a Media provider that contains meta data for all available media on both internal and external storage devices.I am not sure,but the path you are using maybe is not visible for MediaStore.If you are using MediaPlayer do like this...

```
 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(uriOfYourFile));
 int duration = mp.getDuration();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you've already got the Uri or the file path to the video, it might be easier to use the [MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) class. It would look something like this:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever r = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
r.setDataSource(filePath);
String durString = r.extractMetadata( MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION );
int duration = Integer.parseInt(durString);
```

Comment: Thx for the response,but I really need to get it like this.